# get stdout from child_process in separate lines?

Tags: node.js, typescript, child-process

how can i return the output from a child-process with new lines?
this is the function i made, but it returns everything in one line...

```
return new Promise<string>((resolve, rejects) => {
    const bat = exec(getBluetoothDevices);
    if (bat.stdout) {
        bat.stdout.on('data', (data: string) => {
            resolve(data + "\n")
        });
    }
    if (bat.stderr) {
        bat.stderr.on('data', (data: string) => {
            rejects(data.toString())
        });
    }

    // bat.on('exit', (code: string, ) => {
    //     console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`)
    //     resolve(output)
    // })
});
```

any idea would be great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you using a promise? This is going to return the first chunk of stdout data from the process, send that data to whoever's waiting for it by resolving the promise, and now you're never getting the rest of the stdout data because a resolved promise is done, it's not going to keep resolving. This is one of those times where you _actually_ want a callback function instead, so that it can trigger over and over.

Comment: hi, simple answer - because i dont know better ;). i want to await the response of "hcitool scan" wich plots all available bluetooth devices. what do you mean by chunk? is it a certain size or you mean the first time the process writes data?

Comment: I mean that a subprocess can write to stdout several times. Each time it does, the `data` event triggers with that new data. Think of it what happens when the process runs two or more console.logs: this code will only ever deal with the first one, and never handle the rest.

Comment: ok, i understand! lets say it does fire only once - shouldn't it still generate some kind of a new line like \n ?

Comment: It generates what it generates. If the `data` event gives you a buffer without newlines, then the tool did not generate newlines in its output. However, one thing to note is that your typing is wrong: `data` is not a string, it's [a string _or_ buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#event-data). You can _force_ it into a string by using `data.toString()` with optional encoding indicator, though.